# How does text encoding from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer differ from the old tfds.deprecated.text.TokenTextEncoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, tensorflow2.0

#### tfds.deprecated.text.TokenTextEncoder

In the deprecated encoding method with tfds.deprecated.text.TokenTextEncoder
We first create a vocab set of token

```py
tokenizer = tfds.deprecated.text.Tokenizer()
vocabulary_set = set()

#imdb_train --> imdb dataset from tensorflow_datasets
for example, label in imdb_train:
    some_tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(example.numpy())
```

Then load it into the encoder

```py
encoder = tfds.deprecated.text.TokenTextEncoder(vocabulary_set,
                                                   lowercase=True,
                                                   tokenizer=tokenizer)
```

Afterward when performing encoding I notice the encoder will output a single integer, for example while debugging I found that the word "the" got encoded with 112

```py
 token_id = encoder.encode(word)[0]
>> token_id = 112
```

But then when it comes to

#### tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer

```py
tokenizer = tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(words)
token_id = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(word) #word = the
>> token_id = [800,2085,936]
```

It produces a sequence of 3 integers, so now do I use all 3 numbers or should it be also correct if I take just 1 number in that sequence? I'm trying to use this encoded integer to create embedding matrix using Glove Embedding. The old deprecated one produces just one integer so it's easier to map, with integer sequence I'm not sure how to proceed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try something like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

lines = ['You are a fish', 'This is a fish', 'Where are the fishes']
tokenizer = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(lines)
text_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(lines)
text_sequences = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(text_sequences, padding='post')
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
print(tokenizer.word_index)
print(vocab_size)
print(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(['fish'])[0])
```

```
{'are': 1, 'a': 2, 'fish': 3, 'you': 4, 'this': 5, 'is': 6, 'where': 7, 'the': 8, 'fishes': 9}
10
[3]
```

The index 0 is reserved for the padding token. And then to create the weight matrix with the Glove model, try this:

```py
import gensim.downloader as api
import numpy as np

model = api.load("glove-twitter-25")
embedding_dim = 25
weight_matrix = np.zeros((vocab_size, embedding_dim))
for word, i in tokenizer.word_index.items():
  try:
    embedding_vector = model[word]
    weight_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
  except KeyError:
    weight_matrix[i] = np.random.uniform(-5, 5, embedding_dim)
print(weight_matrix.shape)
# (10, 25)
```